# What software should I use for CVS server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, svn, cvs

We are upgrading our CVS server from an old Windows 2003 box with an ANCIENT CVS server installed on it, to a shiny new server with Windows 2008 R2. Any recommendations / shared experiences with a particular CVS server software to use? Any special tweaks to take into consideration?

WE DO NOT HAVE THE OPTION OF MOVING TO ANOTHER SOURCE CONTROL TECHNOLOGY such as SVN or GIT at this time. I am looking for good CVS server software that would work well with Windows Server 2008 R2.

UPDATE: The challenge was that there were no Windows-based CVS server solutions available. The last supported one finally dropped off of the market this year. So in conclusion, almost 1 year later, we have successfully migrated to SVN.

Comment: um... I'm not a Windows guy, but... CVS?

Comment: What version do you have now?  Do you want to consider Linux server?

Comment: Well, that depends on which side of the fence you sit. Getting shitty won't get you any more/better responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That site has software that's older
>   than what we have now.

So what version of CVS do you have then if it is newer than what the official site offers?

Looking into the status of the project, I [noticed this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System):

> Notably, the development of the
>   Microsoft Windows version of CVS has
>   split off into a separate project
>   named [CVSNT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CVSNT) and has been more active
>   in extending the feature set of the
>   system, even porting the changes back
>   to the UNIX platform under the name
>   CVSNT.

Given that, you should probably look into CVSNT and get the latest version of that (if you don't already have it).

However, none of this really matters, because if you want to stick with with CVS (or something forked from it), you are **not** going to have anything nearly as "shiny" as your server, because **CVS is a legacy version control system whose developers moved on to create Subversion a long time ago**. You should probably move to Subversion too (why would that not be an option actually?) – migrating from CVS to SVN is a breeze in most cases.

Comment: Agreed - and the cvs2svn conversion script makes conversion quite easy.

Comment: If CVSNT is the only CVS server out there that's being actively maintained, then it is what we'll have to go with. I was hoping there were more options??

Comment: I doubt it. We had CVSNT in production until 18 months ago. Your situation is unfortunate that you can't migrate away, because VC systems have come a long way since CVS (as I'm sure you know).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run CVS you want to run CVS.

If you are asking for other options for Revision control you can look at Mecurial, Git, or subversion as those are the top 3 I see used all over.

Answer (score -1):

I would look at Git, Mercurial or if you don't want to use a distributed source control then I would still recommend Subversion. I would definitely switch to something new; just make sure you have a rollback strategy in case things don’t go as planned!

Moving source control is something that should not be rushed and it should be planed way ahead of time to minimized downtime.

Good Luck!

Comment: "We do not have the option of moving away from CVS to another technology such as SVN"...